# Where can I find a gallery of WPF UI examples?

Tags: wpf, windows-os

Does anyone know where I can find a gallery of UIs built with stock WPF controls?

I want to give my business partners examples of what can be (fairly easily) accomplished with the standard WPF controls.

I've seen other threads ask about Windows UIs, but the responses have always been geared towards more custom UI elements and/or generic UX principles.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft produced a PDF called [BookOfWPF](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFPresents/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3536) - and although it's dated 2009 - it's still a nice gallery of different types of WPF apps for different purposes. See also [Family.Show](http://www.vertigo.com/familyshow.aspx#).

I have no idea how much of these are built with *stock* controls, however, so don't know how much this will actually help with your ultimate needs...

Answer (score 2):

The [Silverlight Showcase](http://www.silverlight.net/showcase) is a gallery of applications written in [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net) (Silverlight can be treated as a fairly large subset of WPF for the purposes of this question, so most things you see there can be achieved in WPF as well).

No guarantees that they were done with the stock controls though - WPF is customisable like you wouldn't believe so the stock controls take you a (very) long way but that site is a user-submitted showcase so they could be using anything.

Answer (score 1):

1) [Best WPF open source projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449806/best-wpf-open-source-projects)

2) [Good example WPF applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534328/good-example-wpf-applications)

3) [amCharts](http://wpf.amcharts.com/demo) chart stock controls (just controls)

Answer (score 1):

I find it pretty pathetic, the lack of good Line of Business examples in the WPF/Silverlight domain with any real graphic design behind it. 99% of the stuff out there on public display looks exactly like I'd expect something to look that was completely done by developers (see: not designers).

The one I see listed that looks great is, of course, using Telerik controls (not cheap AT ALL), so its not really a practical example for a small company or a company who doesn't want to lock themselves into 3rd party solutions.

Billy Hollis' WPF talk is legendary ( http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=115 ) but there is virtually nothing going into detail on how he did what he did for his client so...yeah.

Discouraging.